# Simple 2D Array Manipulation

Tags: arrays, 2d, processing

I have a program that loads some numbers into an array

(e.g. `int[][] array1 = {{1,2,3},{3,2,1},{2,3,1}};`)

Later in the program (after initialization), I want to change those values. The only way I know to do this is something like this:

```java
array1[0][0] = 3; array1[1][0] = 2; array1[2][0] = 1;
array1[0][0] = 2; array1[1][0] = 3; array1[2][0] = 1;
array1[0][0] = 1; array1[1][0] = 2; array1[2][0] = 3;
```

This is quite bulky and makes the code much more difficult to look at. I want to know if you can change an array's values after initialization with something like this:

```java
int[][] array1 = {{1,2,3},{3,2,1},{2,3,1}};
void main {
    array1 = {{3,2,1},{2,3,1},{1,2,3}};
}
```

If it helps, I'm using Processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: **no**, you can't re-initialize an array like that. You can only use hardcoded arrays like that during the initialization of a variable.

That being said, you could do something ilke this:

```java
int[][] array1 = {{1,2,3},{3,2,1},{2,3,1}};
void setup() {
    int[][] array2 = {{3,2,1},{2,3,1},{1,2,3}};
    array1 = array2;
}
```

You could also use a for loop to set the values in your array.